Anyway to sample UV in Geometry nodes?
I want to try to do some particle surfing in Geometry nodes. However, I need to be able to sample the UV to update the position.
At the moment I have a plane with the texture and a simulation zone that just raycasts down to the plane. I then hope to get the position on the plane that the ray hits and sample the UV there. However, it doesn't seem to work.
Plane

Particles above plane

Sample the Image on Plane

However, this raycast sampling only returns (0,0).
I imainge the UV isn't in the correct domain to sample like this. But if anyone can think of a better UV sampling solution I'm open to it.

Oh wait. I think I just solved this.

Okay, you solved it... would be great for others who have similar problems if you could post your solution here. I'm not sure if I really understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "UV sampling solution"? What are you sampling from the UV?

No worries I shall. Just needed to be sure its doing what I wanted. Which it does.

The correct way to do this is sample the UVMap and then feed that into the image texture

Now the particles flow along with the gradients in the picture

